# android google map v2 --- tilt reset to zero after clicking compass...

Tags: android, google-maps

I have try the google map v2 example, the "Camera". I know the code below set the tilt to 50 to enable the 3D tilt feature.

```
static final CameraPosition BONDI =
        new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(-33.891614, 151.276417))
                .zoom(15.5f)
                .bearing(300)
                .**tilt(50)**
                .build();
```

But after clicking the google map compass, the "tilt" seems to be set to zero, now the 3D feature disappeared and just like a original 2d map.

My problem is how to reset the "tilt" back. I know one way to do that is using "moveCamera()" and give it a CameraUpdate with a "tilt". But is there any other way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drag two fingers down just as in the Google maps app.

Comment: Drag two fingers down just as in the Google maps app ? But my Google map app use the "Current location" button on the top-right corner to change to 3D tilt feature. Do not understand what the drag 2 fingers dwon ...

Comment: Finally, I got the answer here, http://support.google.com/gmm/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1079041.  "To tilt the map, touch an area with two fingers and drag them from top to bottom in parallel to see an angled view of the map. Drag from bottom to top to return to an overhead view."